# Changes done in default managed_schema file is not reflected

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I've added a new filter in managed_schema file for the field type text_general_rev then restarted the solr server and created a new collection with the field type text_general_rev. However, System is not considering the changes done in managed_schema file located in "/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf".

```
<fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
            maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
    <!--Phrase frequency-->
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false"/>     
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
  </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

While am checking the configuration changes in solr admin page changes are not reflected.

[image: configset cloud tree]

Comment: Are you running Solr in cloud mode? I.e. do you have collections in your admin ui and not cores? If that's the case, the configuration is stored in zookeeper and not directly on disk beneath the core/collection directories.

Comment: @MatsLindh I am unable to locate the config files in zookeeper directory.

Comment: You're not supposed to manipulate the files on disk under zookeeper - they're stored in an internal structure to Zookeeper. Use the `downconfig` and `upconfig` commands as shown in [Using Zookeeper to manage configuration files](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/using-zookeeper-to-manage-configuration-files.html).